# How common is cats' love for computer keyboards?

Tags: cats, behavior

One of my 'issues' is the need to move my cat's paws or head off of my keyboard. He just loves to sleep on my 'affairs!'

I even had to take off the 'Screenshot' key (because it caused so many unwanted incidents. Imagine having to close 42 windows!)

So I'm wondering about the frequency and intensity of cats desire to lie on keyboards and if there's any possible cure for that?

Comment: [Related](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-off-my-keyboard)

Comment: My cat seemed to like to smack the "power off" button. I needed to pull it off anyway, as I hit it by mistake. In an odd reverse of your case, though, the Windows shut down got stalled because I always had some screenshots I hadn't saved in MSPaint.

Answer (score 8):

This might sound strange but cats do not love keyboards or laptops or books.

It is you that causes the cat's behaviour. You are giving the computer or the book a lot of attention, so in your cats mind this must be interesting.

The cat sees you sitting relaxed reading on screen or in your book and the cat thinks this is a good time to get some attention.

My cat does walk in front of my monitor for a short time before she lies down on my PC table. She likes to sleep/relax close to me (she is lying by my side right now).

Answer (score 4):

Cats love warm places and they love to be the center of attention (as trond hansen already remarked). A laptop keyboard combines both characteristics and is twice as interesting for cats.

If you want to keep your cat off your keys, teach him that he's not supposed to sit on it by pushing him off. Offer him a more intetesting and comfortable alternative like a carton. Cats love cartons because they have insulating properties and feel warm to them. (This is also the reason why cats sit on books or papers.) Move the carton close to your screen but conveniently out of your way.